# Partial sum of $k>2$ consecutive positive integers has no solution in prime

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

**Progress:**

> Let $a_1,...,a_k$ a sequence of $k$ consecutive positive integers. If $k>2$, show that no partial sum of the sequence $a_1+...+a_k$ has a solution in prime.
>
> I made a heuristic attempt and found a pattern in the progression below:

$$x$$ $$x+(x+1)=2x+1$$ $$x+(x+1)+(x+2)=3x+3$$ $$x+(x+1)+(x+2)+(x+3)=4x+6$$ $$x+(x+1)+(x+2)+(x+3)+(x+4)=5x+10$$ $$x+(x+1)+(x+2)+(x+3)+(x+4)+(x+5)=6x+15$$ $$x+(x+1)+(x+2)+(x+3)+(x+4)+(x+5)+(x+6)=7x+21$$ $$...$$

> Which clearly shows that after $2$nd line each right-hand side value tend to have a common factor greater than $1$ and implies they cannot be prime. Although, technically it's not a proof, so I would appreciate any elementary proof on this matter.

Regards

Comment: If you find a formula for the sum $1 + 2 + \dotsc + (k-2) + (k-1)$, it will be easy to see.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? @DanielFischer

Comment: Hint: for reasons that are clear from the lovely array of equations in your question, numbers of the form in Daniel's comment are called triangular numbers. Google may now be able to help.

Comment: $$x + (x+1) + (x+2) + \dotsc + (x+k-1) = k\cdot x + \bigl( 1 + 2 + \dotsc + (k-1)\bigr).$$ If you find the formula for the sum, it is easy to see that this sum always has a nontrivial factor in common with $k$ (when $k > 2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum $a+(a+1)+\dots + (a+k-1)$ is equal to $\frac{k(2a+k-1)}{2}$.

If $k>2$ then both $k$ and $(2a+k-1)>2$. So your number is the product of two numbers that are larger than $1$.